# How can I make a single RLS role in power BI with multiple values?

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security

I am trying to make several roles in PBI but if I select more than variable, my rule won't work. Example

```
[Company Profile Country] = "US" && [Company Profile Country] = "CA"
```

I don't get any error messages, but nothing shows up when I 'view as'. Any thoughts? If I do just US or just CA then it works fine.

Comment: Yes, that's a logical error you're making. How can something be in US and CA at the same time?

Comment: @W.B Thanks, I was just using that as an example. OR is not working for row level security. Using OR  doesn't work in a powerbi DAX statement, and if I separate the two by commas it does not give me results.

Comment: I don't mean OR literally, but `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: And OR does work, but as a function. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/or-function-dax

Comment: Thank you. That is working for me now but still not fully solving what I am trying to do here.  

[Company Profile Country] = "US" && [Company Division] = "ABC"

I now need to filter based 2 different things, so I am trying to create a role where the user can see only company ABC in the US. This DAX code above doesn't give any error message but also isn't working.

Comment: Well, you're not giving an awful lot of detail here - it's impossible to tell anything, unless you provide sample data that you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong logical operator. You want to display data if it belongs to `US` **OR** if it belongs to `CA`. So the operator should be `||` instead of `&&`.